# where i can find input panel, i can't find it in toolbox?

Tags: dll, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7, sip

I want to handle SIP. So i have gone through the article http://www.christec.co.nz/blog/archives/42
. I don't find Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms.dll in the references. Then i downloaded the dll and tried to add it to the project, then it gives an error that it can't be added because its not build in Microsoft.Phone.Runtime environment.
So how can i get the dll and input panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dll is for Windows CE, which is **NOT** the same as Windows Phone 7. The SIP for WP7 is handled by the operating system and is displayed automatically when a text input control receives focus (`TextBox`, `PasswordBox`, etc).

There is an article that discusses [creating a Bulgarian keyboard](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-Phone-7-Creating-Custom-Keyboard.aspx), but it requires a custom input control, too.